# Do I need to hire an electrician to turn off my main?

Tags: electrical-panel

My service panel (newly installed) does not have a main breaker.  I'm guessing the main breaker is outside in the panel shown with the utility lock tag.  Am I not "allowed" to turn off my main breaker?  My intention is to run a 20 amp circuit for a couple outlets in the basement.

[image: Is the main breaker inside this locked panel?]
[image: Inside panel]

Comment: That's odd that the utility sealed the *customer* compartment on your meter-main.  Who's your utility?  If it were me, I'd just cut the seal on that lower compartment, given that you have an overhead service anyway, so there's going to be nothing in the UG feed gutter on the meter main....

Comment: I'd call the utility and ask them to remove the seal from the customer side of your meter-main.  Hopefully they'll send the person who did it lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close the loop: I contacted the electrician who did the installation. The lower lock tag can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a renter?

I'd call your utility and pretty please ask them why they might have sealed your customer shutoff. Send them the photo.

Otherwise... you don't have a main breaker (if that's what's not in the little box) and I'd be very, very scared.